# Sendmail\Postfix + Milter\Mimedefang: how to encrypt and sign and emails?

Tags: email, encryption, sendmail, postfix-mta, sign

I want to encrypt and sign all emails. In console this is possible by following lines:

```
openssl smime -sign -in ml.txt -signer my.pem -text \
    | openssl smime -encrypt -out mail.msg \
    -from steve@openssl.org -to someone@somewhere \
    -subject "Signed and Encrypted message" -des3 user.pem
```

I have installed postfix (or if it necessarily sendmail) and mimdefang. How to setup mimdefang  or other daemon that use milter API to catch all emails sign and encrypt them and send to the recipients?

Comment: Usually, one would use GPG on client-side to sign and encrypt emails. I guess you want it to be done transparent for users. But this is hard to achieve because you will have to manage all keys on server-side.

Comment: I should use X509 because of requirements.